# Is there any test of power consumption of m2 ssd disks?

Tags: ssd

I have laptop with 500gb m2 ssd and I'd like to have 1/2TB. I sometimes needed to work with bigger data so I'd like to have at least 1TB. Somewhere I saw that the 2TB disk had 50% more consumption than 1TB while doing work.

What are your recommendations? I'll just put some random disks I found.

- Samsung 980 PRO
- Samsung 970 EVO
- WD Blue SN570
- WD Black SN850
- WD Black SN750

Comment: https://ssdsphere.com/ssd-power-consumption-comparison/

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/797011/why-smaller-ssds-are-slower-than-larger-ssds/

Comment: *Larger SSDs Have More Data Channels and DRAM* so I believe yes, a larger SSD type disk regardless of being SATA or NVMe will consume more power, albeit of only a few watts if not milliwatts.  For a laptop on battery power, then the numbers are the numbers and yes a smaller capacity ssd would allow laptop battery to last longer for that technical reason; but at such a lower power number comparatively to laptop screen power draw it probably would be insignificant

Answer (score 1):

There is a test using a PCIe to M.2 card (used by Tweakers.net) to test power draw, although most SSD's don't use much power. As for your SSD choice, the Samsung 970 Evo may be best, since it's not ultra high-end so has less chance of overheating in your laptop. (Note I'm not talking about battery drain, that is not an issue with basically all SSDs)